# Time Label Not Updating

Tags: swift, date, time

I have created a label which displays UTC time upon loading of the app.
Although, it doesn't constantly update and just stays the same value. It only updates when you reload and open the app again.

```
    //UTC Time Formatter
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"

        //UTC Time
    let utcFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 30)
    let utcLbl = UILabel(frame: utcFrame)
    utcLbl.text = "\(dateFormatter.string(from: Date())) UTC"
    let item = UIBarButtonItem(customView: utcLbl)
    self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItems([item], animated: true)
```

This is my code in the viewDidLoad()

Comment: Have you tried introducing a timer which update the label?

Comment: I've tried that but what would I put in the function of updating the label??? @Tobias

Comment: You connect your label to a `IBOutlet` in the code, which you reference from a function executed by a `Timer`, much like M.Hem suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a timer to call a function to update your labels

```
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(runSomeFunc), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Then in the function update your labels

```
func runSomeFunc(){
    //update labels
}
```

Comment: I know how to do that. What i ended up doing was this inside the func:                                                         let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
        formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
            utcLbl.text = formatter.string(from: Date()) + " UTC"